# custom sum elements by key using lodash

Tags: lodash

I do have two objects containing keys like

```
var a = {bar:[1,2], foo:[7,9]}
var b = {bar:[2,2], foo:[3,1]}
```

I want to get the fallowing results:

```
var c = {bar:[3,4], foo:[10,10]}
```

I already have a `for` logic like:

```
for (let key in b) {
  if (a[key]) {
      a[key][0] += b[key][0];
      a[key][1] += b[key][1];
  } 
  else a[key] = b[key];
}
```

But I would like to make this logic in a lodash way. How can I Do it?

Comment: The `for` loop looks simpler, readable and probably gives better performance than the lodash solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create a function that takes `n` objects, and collects them to an array using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Now you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array into [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith) to combine the objects, and in the customizer function sum the items in the arrays using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or lodash's [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) and [`_.add()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#add):

```js
const { mergeWith, isArray, map, add } = _

const fn = (...rest) => _.mergeWith({}, ...rest, (o = [], s) =>
  map(s, (n, i) => add(n, o[i]))
)

const a = {bar:[1,2], foo:[7,9]}
const b = {bar:[2,2], foo:[3,1]}
const c = {bar:[3,2], foo:[5,6]}
const d = {bar:[4,2], foo:[5,4]}

const result = fn(a, b, c, d)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) to create a function that merges all values to a multidimensional array with `_.mergeAllWith()`, then transpose the arrays using `_.zipAll()`, and sums each array:

```js
const { rest, flow, mergeAllWith, isArray, head, mapValues, zipAll, map, sum } = _

const fn = rest(flow(
  mergeAllWith((o, s) => [...isArray(head(o)) ? o : [o], s]), // combine to a multidimensional array
  mapValues(flow(
    zipAll,
    map(sum)
  )),
))

const a = {bar:[1,2], foo:[7,9]}
const b = {bar:[2,2], foo:[3,1]}
const c = {bar:[3,2], foo:[5,6]}
const d = {bar:[4,2], foo:[5,4]}

const result = fn(a, b, c, d)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using plain JavaScript with `Object.entries`, `concat` and `reduce`:

```js
const a = { bar: [1,2], foo: [7,9] };
const b = { bar: [2,2], foo: [3,1] };

const entries = Object.entries(a).concat(Object.entries(b));

const result = entries.reduce((accum, [key, val]) => {
  accum[key] = accum[key] ? accum[key].map((x, i) => x + val[i]) : val;
  return accum;
}, { });

console.log(result);
```